# GWT BOOTSTRAP - Question

Tags: javascript, gwt

Reading the GWT Bootstrap on Googles page, i have some question.
(http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit-doc-1-5/wiki/FAQ_WhenDoModulesLoad )

Assumptions:
Most browsers will allow a maximum of two simultaneous connections for fetching resources.

The HTML Page:

`<html>
     <body onload='alert("w00t!")'>
    <img src='bigImageZero.jpg'></img>
    <script source='externalScriptZero.js'></script>
    <img src='bigImageOne.jpg'></img>
    <img src='reallyBigImageTwo.jpg'></img>
    <script src='com.example.app.App.nocache.js'></script>
    <script src='externalScriptOne.js'></script>
  </body>
</html>`

So , the bootstrap is composed of:

1. The HTML document is fetched and parsing begins.
2. Begin fetching bigImageZero.jpg.
3. Begin fetching externalScriptZero.js.
4. bigImageZero.jpg completes (let's assume). Parsing is blocked until     externalScriptZero.js is done fetching and evaluating.
5. externalScriptZero.js completes.
6. Begin fetching bigImageOne.jpg and reallyBigImageTwo.jpg simultaneously.
7. bigImageOne.jpg completes (let's assume again). com.example.app.App.nocache.js begins fetching and evaluating.
8. ...nocache.js completes, and the compiled script (...cache.js) begins fetching (this is non-blocking).
9. ...cache.js completes. onModuleLoad() is not called yet, as we're still waiting on externalScriptOne.js to complete before the document is considered 'ready'.
10. externalScriptOne.js completes. The document is ready, so onModuleLoad() fires.
11. reallyBigImageTwo.jpg completes.
12. body.onload() fires, in this case showing an alert() box.

    **The question:**

    how the JAVASCRIPT knows that the document is ready to begin onModuleLoad function ( step 10 ) ?

Comment: Your question is very unclear grammatically.

What exactly do you want to know?

Comment: How onModuleLoad function ( javascript ) is able to wait until the document be "ready"

Answer (score 2):

From the same page:

- `<img>` tags are not guaranteed to be done loading when `onModuleLoad()` is called.
- `<script>` tags **are** guaranteed to be done loading when `onModuleLoad()` is called.

So when `onModuleLoad()` is executed the externalScriptOne.js is loaded, it doesn't start before all script tags are loaded.

Comment: So, the OnModuleLoad wasn't fired because the parser is fetching the externalScriptOne.js . right ? thanks in advance

Comment: yes that is correct. it's not fired until the externalStricptOne.js is loaded. I'm not sure if this is a feature of script tags or if GWT registers itself at body.onload. But as mentioned it is guaranteed all scripts are loaded when onModuleLoad is called.

Comment: Maybe the GWT register anything on Body.OnLoad Event. u are right, im looking for this in the GWT Compiled Script. But from the google´s page  "<img> tags are not guaranteed to be done loading when onModuleLoad() is called." break the theory about body.onLoad event.

Answer (score 0):

either nocache.js or cache.js could add an extra `<script>` tag immediately after the last `<script>` tag.  this extra `<script>` tag would not be fetched until all previous `<script>` tags are fetched, parsed, and evaluated.  then this `<script>` tag would be fetched, executed, and evaluated without waiting for any images.  the evaluation of this `<script>` tag could call `onModuleLoad()` and it would not wait for any images so it would happen sooner than body.onload

this is just my theory; i could not verify it in my development server and i have not attempted to verify it on appengine.